# swift optional parameter function

Tags: swift, optional-parameters

In swift, how to define a function with a optional parameter who is a function?
For instance, I have a function like this:
func test(handler: Int -> Void)
I expect the parameter handler be optional, actually, this means the handler parameter type should be optional function, so how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other type really. So for the non-optional:

```
func test(handler: (Int) -> (Void))
```

the optional version would become:

```
func test(handler: ((Int) -> (Void))?)
```

Another way to think about this is, if we were to create a `typealias` for the handler it would be something like:

```
typealias handlerCallback = (Int) -> (Void)

func test(handler: handlerCallback)  // The non-optional version
func test(handler: handlerCallback?) // The optional version
```

I hope that this makes sense

Comment: Seems to be broken in Swift 3.1

Comment: @StevenKramer Edited. Thanks for that :)